# Copy a GCR image from one project to another

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry, google-vpc

I aim to copy a gcr image from one project to another as soon as the image lands in the container registry of the first project. I am aware of the **gcloud container images add-tag** command, looking for a more automated option. Also the second project where the image has to be copied is protected by VPC-SC. Any leads will be appreciated...

Answer (score 4):

I understand that you are looking for the best way to mirror the GCR images between two projects. Currently, you can follow the workaround in this document [click](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/managing#copying_images_to_a_new_registry) to copy the container images for your use case. At the moment, the only way to move between two registries is by pulling from one and pushing to another, if you have the right permission. There is currently a tool on github that can automate this for you, gcrane [click](https://github.com/google/go-containerregistry/blob/master/cmd/gcrane/README.md) . However, for mirroring the container images between two projects, a feature request has already been submitted but there is no ETA.

According to the GCP documentation [click](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/supported-products#registry) , If the project is protected by VPC-SC, the container registry does not use googleapis.com domain. To achieve this, container registry need to configured via private DNS or BIND to map to the restricted VIP separately from other APIs.

Answer (score 1):

When a change is made to a container registry that you own, a Pub/Sub message can be published.  You can use this Pub/Sub message as a trigger to perform work.  My immediate thought would be to create a Cloud Function that is triggered by the arrival of a message which then fires off a Cloud Build recipe.  The Cloud Build would perform a docker pull of your original image and then a tag rename and then a docker push.  It feels like this would be 100% automated and use components that are designed for CI/CD pipelines.

References:

- [Configuring Pub/Sub notifications](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/configuring-notifications)
- [Cloud Build documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/)